# I cannot turn Google Safesearch off

Tags: internet, google-search

[image: cannot turn safesearch off]

I am using a "BT Wifi with Fon" hotspot that I paid for. BT says my internet traffic goes through a unique channel from everyone else who is using that hotspot or wifi, so whoever owns the router or broadband my wifi is coming from, did not use Parental Controls to modify my Google settings.

I have contacted my ISP and they said they don't control or modify the Google settings.

I have disabled all my security software and used a different web browser and it didn't help.

I have taken `safe=active` query string out the URL and it didn't help.

I have checked my hosts file and there's nothing unusual there.

How do I fix this and turn Safesearch off?

Comment: Possibly relevant: https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/websearch/QKVKcDhCdWA

Answer (score 2):

Since this still shows up in search results for this question...

The issue is that BT SafeBrowsing filters enforce SafeSearch, and it's on by default on BT internet accounts (and not just Fon)

> For BT Parental Controls we’re introducing SafeSearch and making it
> part of the product. This means, regardless of the filter level or
> time-based filter you've turned on, you'll always benefit from
> SafeSearch so long as you're on BT broadband and have BT Parental
> Controls turned on.
>
> All devices at home using BT broadband or any of the five million BT
> Wi-Fi hotspots will automatically benefit from SafeSearch. Any
> SafeSearch settings that might already be in place will be overridden,
> and to turn off SafeSearch you'll need to turn off Parental Controls
> or customise the time Parental Controls comes on.

From [https://bt.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/64721/~/safesearch-on-bt-parental-controls](https://bt.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/64721/%7E/safesearch-on-bt-parental-controls)

Comment: Could you add the quote from the website that you have found this information? Websites can move or disappear and the answer is lost

Comment: I sent BT an email and they said it was because the media started talking about children having access to porn online, which then put pressure on the government to implement the Friendly Wifi scheme. It mandates by law that all public hotspots have parental controls turned on by default and that safesearch is forced to be on, and you can't enter any driving license number or passport number to prove you're 18 to turn it off. BT said that they don't want to implement this but the government forced it in by law. BT did not disclose which charities, media, groups  or people campaigned for this.

Comment: It happened when David Cameron was prime minister.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this problem with BT on my iPhone this morning.

BT filter the content that goes via their DNS.

You can circumnavigate this on your device by changing your internet / wifi connection settings and manually setting your DNS to something other than your local router (e.g 192.168.1.1 and/or ipv6 equivalent).

Set the DNS to something like 8.8.8.8 (google), or 1.1.1.1 (cloud flare), or 208.67. 222.222 (Open DNS).